# Custom order with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (table1.first_key, table1.second_key) IN ((2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2));
```

I want to have the result it the order of the IN (....) content.

If it was only one column, I could have used:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(table1.first_key, 1, 5, 4, 7)
```

I don't figure out how to have the same result with multiple columns in a good MySQL way.

Here is my best try so far, it works, but will be slow on huge table :

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_key, "_", second_key) AS string_hack, first_key, second_key,....
FROM table1
WHERE (first_key, second_key) IN ((2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2))
ORDER BY FIELD(string_hack, "2_1", "1_1", "2_2")
```

That works, but it stinks.

There must be a better way

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is going to be fast and your approach may be quite reasonable.  You don't need to have a column called `string_hack`.  You can just do:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(CONCAT_WS('_', first_key, second_key),
               '2_1', '1_1', '2_2;
              )
```

You might also consider switching to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as ordering, 2 as key1, 1 as key1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 1, 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, 2, 2
     ) keys
      ON t1.first_key = keys.key1 AND t1.second_key = keys.key2
ORDER BY keys.ordering;
```

Comment: Interesting approach.